# Rotate path element without transform property

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way to rotate path element about its center by including the rotation within the ***d*** property, without using the ***transform*** property.

Comment: why would you not want to use the obvious transform property?

Comment: @RobertLongson I am using threejs library to convert svg to webgl, which doesnt support rotation in elliptical arc.